# JIT ForceDirected Graph with fixed node position

Tags: javascript, json, graph, jit, thejit

My web service returns json with all nodes of a grath set. I'm using the JIT for visualisation. Does JIT allow to set positions of each node inside json? 
Or is there any javascript library which allows this?

Comment: Did you have any luck in finding a library?

Comment: i kept using jit just found a way how to specify fixed position of each node.

Comment: can you share how you did that?

Comment: in JIT initialization I would point to method from a bean that returns calculated json